# NullPointer adapter при переходе с интента

Tags: java, android

Я в андроиде еще новичек поэтому иногда не могу понять по каким причинам в нем происходят некоторые ошибки, в гугле ничего так и не нашел.

В общем есть активити с listview и адаптером к нему, где адаптер имеет модель, при первой инициализации активити и переходе с другого активити все работает нормально, далее я перехожу в третье активити и когда пытаюсь вернуться в активити с адаптером выскакивает NullPointer, вопрос почему?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.yar, PID: 2752
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yar/com.yar.ExerciseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.yar.resourses.ExersiceModelAdapter.getCount(ExersiceModelAdapter.java:27)
                      at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:480)
                      at com.yar.ExerciseActivity.onCreate(ExerciseActivity.java:38)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

класс с адаптером:

```
package com.yar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.yar.resourses.ExersiceModel;
import com.yar.resourses.ExersiceModelAdapter;
import com.yar.resourses.Requests;
import com.yar.serialize.Serialize;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExerciseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    // private static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private String currentIntentDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);

        currentIntentDay = getIntent().getStringExtra(Requests.DAY_POSITION);
        Serialize.getExersices(currentIntentDay);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_ExerciseActivity);

        // создаем адаптер
        ExersiceModelAdapter adapter = new ExersiceModelAdapter(this, initData() );
```

ругается именно на это строку:

```
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);



           listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    // TODO
                    // здесь передаем название

                }
            });
        }

        public void button_Exercise_Add(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListExerciseActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        private List<ExersiceModel> initData() {
            List<ExersiceModel> list = new ArrayList<>();



            list = Serialize.myDaysMap.get(currentIntentDay);

            return list;
        }


    }
```

модель:

```
package com.yar.resourses;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.yar.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExersiceModelAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<ExersiceModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ExersiceModelAdapter(Context context, List<ExersiceModel> list) {
        this.list = list;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            //импорт layout должен быть из своего проекта
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

        }

        ExersiceModel exersiceModel = getExersiceModel(position);

        TextView txtExersice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Exersice);
        txtExersice.setText(exersiceModel.getExersiceName());
        TextView txtApproach = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Approach);
        txtApproach.setText(String.valueOf(exersiceModel.getApproach()));
        TextView txtReiteration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Reiteration);
        txtReiteration.setText(String.valueOf(exersiceModel.getReiteration()));



        return view;
    }

    private ExersiceModel getExersiceModel(int position) {
        return (ExersiceModel) getItem(position);
    }
}
```

и вот на эту

```
 return list.size();
```

я так понимаю коллекция по каким то причинам в моделе становится пустой, вопрос почему так происходит ?

задача данного активити перенимать значения хранящиеся в другой коллекции, в другом классе каждый раз при открытии этого активити, т.к. значения той колеекции могут меняться

Comment: `Serialize.myDaysMap` - что это? Оно у вас `null` возвращает.

Comment: Как возвращаетесь: `finish()`, кнопкой назад, `startActivity(...)` ?

Comment: @Suvitruf это мапа из класса, в ней содержатся данные для отображения моего listview

Comment: @woesss через интент startActivity(intent);

Comment: Тогда Вы не возвращаетесь а скорее всего запускаете новый экземпляр этой активности (зависит от флагов интента и атрибутов в манифесте) и в новый интент не добавляете `Extra(Requests.DAY_POSITION)` - отсюда и проблема. Для возвращения в предыдущую активность не нужно вызывать `startActivity(...)`, нужно просто закрыть текущую вызовом `finish()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема заключалась в

```
private String currentIntentDay;
```

который null, т.к. он инициализируется при переходе с первого активити, а не третьего с которого крашится.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ExersiceModel exersiceModel = getExersiceModel(position);

    TextView txtExersice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Exersice);
    txtExersice.setText(exersiceModel.getExersiceName());
    TextView txtApproach = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Approach);
    txtApproach.setText(String.valueOf(exersiceModel.getApproach()));
    TextView txtReiteration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Reiteration);
    txtReiteration.setText(String.valueOf(exersiceModel.getReiteration()));
```

Вы слишком рано вызываете findViewById (), когда инициализируете объект настроек активности, вероятно, переменную-член. Код, который вы опубликовали, не показывает этого.

Вы действительно можете вызвать функции активности только в onCreate () или позже.

Также поместите findViewById () после setContentView (), чтобы он мог фактически вернуть что-то отличное от нуля.